# Mongodb cannot connect to port 27018

Tags: mongodb

When I run the below command in CMD under Mongodb bin folder, it prompts an error message.
Can someone help me on this?

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27018
```

Here is the error prompt:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27018, connection attempt failed: 
SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27018 :: caused by :: No connection 
could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb bydefault runs on `localhost` using port `27017`, you do not need to explicitly mention that just use `mongod` command and it will start your mongodb server. If you want to run on specific port then `mongod --port 27018` should work

Comment: But I want it to connect to other ports like 27018, 27019 from cmd command for the purpose of sharding or replicate.

Answer (score 0):

`mongo` is just the CLI interface.

Use:

```
mongod --port 27019
```

Look here for more detail: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-tcp-port